# pregmatch for url. regex

Tags: php, regex, validation

I have a regex that validate a specific url but it not really working.  I want to validate urls like this -----> https : // example.co.nz/#![RANDOM_KEYS_HERE].
I want to do it only with https.  Most importantly, the input of the user need to match https : // example.co.nz/#! but after the #!, the user can put anything he like.

Here is the code:
I know that the code is fked up xD I have a basic knowledge in that lol

```
#^https://example+\.[co\.nz][a-z0-9-_.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}#i
```

If anyone could help me to do it, it would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
^https:\/\/example\.co\.nz\/\#\!(.*)$
```

The parentheses at the end will do a sub-expression match which should allow you to pull out the ID.

```
if (preg_match('/^https:\/\/example\.co\.nz\/\#\!(.*)$/', $searchString, $matches)) {
    $id = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Erm... not even close. Your regex reads as follows:

- Starting from the beginning of the string...
- Match literally `https://exampl`
- Match one or more `e`
- Match a literal `.`
- Match one of any of these: `cnoz.`
- Match one or more of these: `a-z0-9-_.`
- Match a literal `.`
- Match between 2 and 4 letters

This is nothing like what you're looking for. After all, I don't think you want this to pass:

```
https://exampleeeeeeeeeeee.complete.and.total.failure.-_-.lol
```

Instead, try this:

```
(^https://example\.co\.nz/#!(.*))
```

This regex reads as follows:

- Starting from the beginning of the string...
- Match literally `https://example.co.nz/#!`
- Capture everything thereafter

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('%^https://example\.co\.nz/#!(.+)$%i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Or you can get your [RANDOM_KEYS_HERE] part with this one

```
if (preg_match('%^https://example\.co\.nz/#!(.+)$%i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regexp there. You just need to find out if string starts with some substring.  Check this:

```
if(strpos($url, 'https://example.co.nz/#!')===0)
{
    echo 'url is OK';
}
else
{
    echo 'url is wrong';
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

I hope this helps.